# FlowJS type and using && with assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, destructuring

Let's say I have the following flowtype:

```
type formExample = {
  +form?: {
    +[string]: {
      values: {
        [string]: string | number | boolean
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which I then consume like so:

```
const { email, password } = form && form.login && form.login.values
```

Which fails flow typechecking with:

```
Property email is missing in undefined [1]
```

I don't understand how email could be undefined and what flow is complaining about?

Comment: What if `form` is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the error.

The type of `form && form.login && form.login.values` is `{...} | undefined` (in case `form` is undefined).

Flow is complaining that your destructuring makes no sense if the value is `undefined`.

Comment: that actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks!